# How to unrar and unzip files recursively?

Tags: bash, zip

I have a huge file that contains zips and rars with zip and rar files located within on a linux box.

I basically need a script or one-liner that will recursively hunt through the directories and unzip and unrar any rar or zip it finds.

Answer (score 1):

Here is someones solution to this with a shell script.

http://www.dbforums.com/unix-shell-scripts/1619154-how-unzip-files-recursively.html

It would seem that Linux does not have a recursive unzip option :(

Comment: It is inappropriate to simply link your source, you should also provide an answer

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of doing this is to loop multiple times with find and execute a script that removes the files after they've been correctly unpacked. It'll have to go over subdirectories multiple times so it's not exactly efficient. (expected filenames in bold on top)

**recursive_unpack**

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -d "$1" ]; then
   STARTDIR="$1"
else
   echo "starting dir not found: $1"
   exit
fi


COUNTER=1
while [ $COUNTER -gt 0 ]; do
   COUNTER=`find "$STARTDIR" -type f \( -iname '*.zip' -o -iname '*.rar' \) -exec ./unpacker \{\} \; | wc -l`
done
```

**unpacker**

```
#!/bin/bash
BASENAME=`basename "$1"`
BASEDIR=`dirname "$1"`

cd "$BASEDIR"
EXT=`echo "$BASENAME" | awk -F . '{print $NF}'`

if [ "$EXT" = "zip" ]; then
  unzip -qq "$BASENAME"
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
     echo "zip unpacked: $1"
     rm "$BASENAME"
  fi
fi

if [ "$EXT" = "rar" ]; then
  unrar e -y -c- -inul "$BASENAME"
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
     echo "rar unpacked: $1"
     rm "$BASENAME"
  fi
fi
```

do

```
chmod u+x recursive_unpack
chmod u+x unpacker
```

call it with `./recursive_unpack "/my/directory/containing/my/files"`

- recursive_unpack expects unpacker in the same directory
- `unrar` and `unzip` need to be installed
- if it can't find the directory it'll exit with an error
- do not remove the echo messages in unpacker, they're used to check for the presence of files to unpack to terminate the loop

Answer (score 1):

A quick one-liner, doesn't check if an archive has already been extracted:

```
$ find . -name '*.rar' -execdir unrar e '{}' + && find . -name '*.zip' -execdir unzip -tq '{}' +
```

Comment: I wonder why unrar requires execdir, after reading the man page I think I'll stop using exec.

Comment: note, edited to add unzip, that's untested

Answer (score 0):

Maybe dtrx (http://brettcsmith.org/2007/dtrx/) will do, though I'm not sure whether it handles rar type.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you will find that you have rar part files, and you may want to remove them aswell together with the *.rar, for this you can add this:

```
find "$BASENAME" -regex '.*\.r[0-9][0-9]' -delete
```

Here:

```
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
     echo "rar unpacked: $1"
     rm "$BASENAME"
     # HERE
  fi
```

And thus the bash will also remove the part files too.